# Mount secondary windows drive on LAN

Tags: networking, mount, windows

I have two computers, a desktop with Ubuntu 17.04 and a notebook with Windows 8. Both are in the same local area network. The notebook's HD has 2 partitions, identified by the drive letters *C:* and *D:*.

Sometimes I need to get files available on the notebook through the desktop. For example, to access *C:\Users\MyName* folder, I do...

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.yy/Users/MyName /mnt/share -o username=foo,password=bar
```

This works perfectly. The question is: How to access a folder that is in the notebook's *D:* drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how windows hidden admin shares work, you are able to do the same thing using the CIFS mount options. The username and password has to be an user account that is in the administrators group on the windows system.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.yy/D$/ /mnt/share -o username=foo,password=bar
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.xx.yy/C$/ /mnt/share -o username=foo,password=bar
```

I have tested the command connecting from an RHEL 7 Server to Windows Server 2012 R2 with no issues.

```
mount -t cifs -o user=thebtm,domain=domain.ad,file_mode=0776,dir_mode=0776 "//servername.domain.ad/C$/" /mnt/windows/C
```